# Одновременное количество RDP-подключений к серверу

Tags: администрирование, windows-server, rdp

Ребята, подскажите такую вещь...имеется сервак, работающий на Windows Server 2008 R2. Люди со своих компом подключаются по RDP к этому серверу (все компы работают в пределах одной локальной сети). Проблема вся в том, что **почему-то** могут работать по RDP одновременно только 2 пользователя...при подключении 3-го вылазиит ошибка типа "превышен лимит RDP подключений".

Подскажите, можно ли где-нибудь либо в реестре, либо в консоли MMC задать число одновременных подключений, либо выставить галку типа "Неограниченное количество RDP-подключений"...

Необходимо реализовать возможность подключения, как минимум, 10 пользователей по RPD одновременно.

Answer (score 2):

Первое что приходит в голову -- а как у вас с [лицензированием служб терминалов](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc754034(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Обычно

> ошибка типа "превышен лимит RDP подключений"

говорит о не установленной службе "Лицензирование служб терминалов" в службах ролей при установке роли терминального сервера (или службах терминалов после установки роли), или неправильной ее настройке. Бывает, что служба в режиме "на устройство", а лицензии - "на пользователя" или наоборот, а бывает, что не активирован сервер лицензий (раньше можно было активировать бесплатно, как щаз - не знаю)...

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю как доберусь до компьютера и отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Помогла статейка в интернете на эту тему.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста;)